# how to use pagination links from json data in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, jquery-pagination

How can I use the links for paginate I return in JSON Response.

This is how I return it

```
 return response()->json(['data' => $data,
                          'pagination' => $data->links()]);
```

This is how I use it but it does not work

```
$('#pagination').html(response['pagination']);
```

This is the response in console.log(response);

```
{data: {…}, pagination: {…}}
  data: {current_page: 1, data: Array(2), first_page_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-orders/2? 
  page=1', from: 1, last_page: 6, …}
  pagination: {}
  [[Prototype]]: Object
```

[image]

This is the response in console.log(response['pagination']);

```
{}
 [[Prototype]]: Object
```

[image]

Comment: This is already the third question you are asking about this topic, within a couple of hours ... Does it need a new one every time, can you not continue the discussion in one place?

Comment: `pagination: {}` - so apparently this is an _empty_ object. Which means, `$data->links()` probably did not return what you expected it to in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe sorry for this but no one reply to my question, probably they dont understand how I wrote it so I tried to explain it simplier,

Comment: can you help me @CBroe, why it return an empty object, as per my research this should do it 'pagination' => (string) $contacts->links() but it return nothing

Comment: Please learn to show a bit more _patience_ first of all then. And if you are worried that people might not have understood what you are asking - then you can edit the existing question, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Did you read [Converting Results To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#converting-results-to-json)? (`->links()` is for _rendering_ the pagination)

Comment: @CBroe understood  won't happen again

Comment: hi @brombeer i tried to understand it but im confuse, sorry im a new to this and trying to learn, can you give me an example base on my code thank you appreciate sir

Comment: You don't need to add the `pagination` to your response. Your `data` object should already have a `links` property which would be an array of objects, each with a `url`, `label`, and if it's `active`. You can then use that to build up your pagination links. You also already have some relative link information such as `first_page_url` and `next_page_url` that you can use if you want

Comment: @aynber I notice that, as per checking using the paginate(5) it gave me a pages but it is not a collection thats why i cant use this $data->links(), is there a way thank you so much

Comment: `$data->links()` is only for the blade templates. If you check out https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination#displaying-pagination-results, you'll see it will render the links to the page, but it apparently won't convert to json. If you want to have the HTML already written and passed to the json, then create a view just for the pagination links, and return the string version of the view.

Comment: Thank you so much  @aynber I understood it in some way, but also confuse, can you please give some example sir just a simple one, Im new  to this and want to learn a lot from all of you. Thank you so much it will help me a lot.

Answer (score -2):

```
$output = '<p>your data</p>';

if($data['current_page']==1){
  $pb = 'disabled';
}else{
  $pb = '';
}
if($data['current_page']==$data['last_page']){
  $pbl = 'disabled';
}else{
  $pbl = '';
}

$prev = $data['current_page']-1;
$nxt = $data['current_page']+1;

$page = '<ul class="pagination">
<li><a  class="gotopage btn" page="'.$prev.'" '. $pb.'> < </a></li>';

for ($i=1; $i <=$data['last_page'] ; $i++) {
    if( $i>=$data['current_page']-5 && $i<=$data['current_page']+5){
  if($data['current_page']==$i){ 
  $page .= '<li><a class="gotopage btn btn-primary" page="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
  }else{
    $page .= '<li><a  class="gotopage btn" page="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
  }
}
}

if($data['current_page']==$data['last_page']){ 
$page .= '<li><a  class="gotopage btn" page="'.$data['last_page'].'" '. $pbl.'> > </a></li></ul>';
}else{
  $page .= '<li><a  class="gotopage btn" page="'.$nxt.'" '. $pbl.'> > </a></li></ul>'; 
}

return json_encode(['data'=>$output,'page'=>$page]);
```

Comment: Please don't just "dump" code. Add some explanation of how your code solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: You can also create a custom pagination buttons using for loop